# Elegant way to perform tuple arithmetic

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, tuples

What is the most elegant and concise way (without creating my own class with operator overloading) to perform tuple arithmetic in Python 2.7?

Lets say I have two tuples:

```
a = (10, 10)
b = (4, 4)
```

My intended result is

```
c = a - b = (6, 6)
```

I currently use:

```
c = (a[0] - b[0], a[1] - b[1])
```

I also tried:

```
c = tuple([(i - j) for i in a for j in b])
```

but the result was `(6, 6, 6, 6)`. I believe the above works as a nested for loops resulting in 4 iterations and 4 values in the result.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of these and they don't particularly need to be _tuples_ you could look at numpy

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you're looking for fast, you can use numpy:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.subtract((10, 10), (4, 4))
array([6, 6])
```

and if you want to keep it in a tuple:

```
>>> tuple(numpy.subtract((10, 10), (4, 4)))
(6, 6)
```

Answer (score 49):

One option would be,

```
>>> from operator import sub
>>> c = tuple(map(sub, a, b))
>>> c
(6, 6)
```

And [`itertools.imap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) can serve as a replacement for `map`.

Of course you can also use other functions from [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) to `add`, `mul`, `div`, etc.

But I would seriously consider moving into another data structure since I don't think this type of problem is fit for `tuple`s

Answer (score 37):

Use `zip` and a generator expression:

```
c = tuple(x-y for x, y in zip(a, b))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> a = (10, 10)
>>> b = (4, 4)
>>> c = tuple(x-y for x, y in zip(a, b))
>>> c
(6, 6)
```

Use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) for a memory efficient solution.

help on `zip`:

```
>>> print zip.__doc__
zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
```

Comment: Just a note on `izip`: In Python 3, the regular `zip` function works like Python 2's `izip` did, so you can just use `zip` as the examples in this answer show.

Answer (score 14):

JFYI, execution time in my laptop in 100000 times iteration

`np.subtract(a, b)` : 0.18578505516052246

`tuple(x - y for x, y in zip(a, b))` : 
0.09348797798156738

`tuple(map(lambda x, y: x - y, a, b))` : 0.07900381088256836

`from operator import sub tuple(map(sub, a, b))` : 0.044342041015625

operator looks more elegant for me.

Comment: you definitely shouldn't use np.subtract if you're converting to and from numpy arrays, but should if you're doing many of these and can keep them in the more reasonable data structure for this task!

Answer (score 7):

This can also be done just as nicely without an import at all, although lambda is often undesirable:

```
tuple(map(lambda x, y: x - y, a, b))
```

If you are looking to get the distance between two points on say a 2d coordinate plane you should use the absolute value of the subtraction of the pairs.

```
tuple(map(lambda x ,y: abs(x - y), a, b))
```

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to Kohei Kawasaki's answer, for speed, the original solution was actually the fastest (For a length two tuple at least).

```
>>> timeit.timeit('tuple(map(add, a, b))',number=1000000,setup='from operator import add; a=(10,11); b=(1,2)')
0.6502681339999867
>>> timeit.timeit('(a[0] - b[0], a[1] - b[1])',number=1000000,setup='from operator import add; a=(10,11); b=(1,2)')
0.19015854899998885
>>>
```

Comment: And what if your tuples have million elements? Are you going to list out the operation one by one?

Comment: @RaminMelikov Fair enough, added a disclaimer

Answer (score 2):

Since in your question there only examples of 2-number-tuples, for such coordinate-like tuples, you may be good with simple built-in "complex" class:

```
>>> a=complex(7,5)
>>> b=complex(1,2)
>>> a-b
>>> c=a-b
>>> c
(6+3j)
>>> c.real
6.0
>>> c.imag
3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

my element-wise tuple arithmetic helper

supported operations: +, -, /, *, d

operation = 'd' calculates distance between two points on a 2D coordinate plane

```
def tuplengine(tuple1, tuple2, operation):
    """ 
    quick and dirty, element-wise, tuple arithmetic helper,
    created on Sun May 28 07:06:16 2017
    ...
    tuple1, tuple2: [named]tuples, both same length
    operation: '+', '-', '/', '*', 'd'
    operation 'd' returns distance between two points on a 2D coordinate plane (absolute value of the subtraction of pairs)
    """
    assert len(tuple1) == len(tuple2), "tuple sizes doesn't match, tuple1: {}, tuple2: {}".format(len(tuple1), len(tuple2))
    assert isinstance(tuple1, tuple) or tuple in type(tuple1).__bases__, "tuple1: not a [named]tuple"
    assert isinstance(tuple2, tuple) or tuple in type(tuple2).__bases__, "tuple2: not a [named]tuple"
    assert operation in list("+-/*d"), "operation has to be one of ['+','-','/','*','d']"
    return eval("tuple( a{}b for a, b in zip( tuple1, tuple2 ))".format(operation)) \
    if not operation == "d" \
      else eval("tuple( abs(a-b) for a, b in zip( tuple1, tuple2 ))")
```