# How to subtract every component available as tuples from a list by list's first value?

Tags: python

How to subtract a every values available in list containing tuples by a list's first value (which is also tuple)?

For example,

I have a list which contains number of tuples. Every tuple consists X and Y coordinates.

```
tuple1 = [(57.4, 213.0), (57.4, 214.0), (58.4, 214.0), (58.4, 213.0), (59.4, 213.0), (60.4, 213.0), (61.4, 213.0), (61.4, 214.0), (60.4, 214.0), (59.4, 214.0), (59.4, 215.0), (60.4, 215.0), (61.4, 215.0), (61.4, 216.0), (60.4, 216.0), (60.4, 217.0), (61.4, 217.0), (59.4, 217.0), (59.4, 216.0)]
```

I want to subtract every value available in list by list's first value, in this case is `tuple1[0]  = (57.4. 213.0)`.

So from 1st component of every tuple, I want to subtract `57.4` and from the second component, I want to subtract `213`.

How would I do this?

Comment: You have to define two variables (let's say xo and yo to store the x and y of your list's 1st element.
Then you have to define a new variable (let's say finalTuple1) to store your results.
Then you have to iterate your list, subtract each element's coordinates and store them into finalTuple1. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, that option I already thought of, but, this can take lot of writing to do a simple task. I am looking forward to find a way to do it in a one or two lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17418273/2417351 Is this one helpful ?

Comment: When calculating with matrixes you should start using `numpy` instead of lists. Lists quickly become slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it worked, I put it as an answer:

```
finalTuple1 = tuple(numpy.subtract(tuple1, tuple1[0]))
```

Note that you have to import:

```
import numpy
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do it with a list comprehension:

```
[(t[0]-tuple1[0][0], t[1]-tuple1[0][1]) for t in tuple1]
```

Comment: It also works well. It is good to know how list comprehension works in my question!