# Subtracting a tuples of the list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples

```py
lst = [(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(7,8,9)]
```

And

I want to find the difference between previous tuple from the next like this:

```py
ans = [(0,0,0), (6,6,6)]
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly do you mean by difference? Substracting each value in the second tuple from the corresponding value in the first tuple or are those coordinates and you are mean distance between two points in that 3d vector space and which distance? Euclidean?

Comment: So you want to go over the tuples in the list in pairs, compute the difference and collect the results in a new list. What part of the problem are you having trouble with? Please share a code example and be specific. You may get someone to do your coding for you, but those types of questions are generally not appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the data and use the `sub` method from the operator package to subtract the tuples:

```py
from operator import sub
data = [(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(7,8,9)]
diff = [tuple(map(sub, data[i+1], data[i])) for i in range(0, len(data)-1)]
```

You could also use a for loop instead of the list comprehension if you prefer. The tuple subtraction is from here: [Elegant way to perform tuple arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418108/elegant-way-to-perform-tuple-arithmetic)

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import reduce, partial
from operator import sub

my_list = [(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(7,8,9)]

diff_list = list(map(partial(reduce, lambda a, b: tuple(map(sub, a, b))), zip(my_list[1:], my_list)))
```

To break it down:

```
zip(my_list[1:], my_list)
```

This creates a new iterator which yields iterables consisting of **every next element of the list followed by the previous**.

```
partial(reduce, lambda a, b: tuple(map(sub, a, b)))
```

This creates a function which when given an iterable whose elements consist of tuples, will return a new tuple containing the difference between the first and the second tuples. It could be more tuples, but in our case, we only ever pass to this function an iterable consisting of two tuples, it will always do what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
lst = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9)]

out = [tuple(b - a for a, b in zip(t1, t2)) for t1, t2 in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (6, 6, 6)]
```